# How to export test cases from Rally on to a CSV file

Tags: rally

I would like to export test cases along with the test steps from rally onto a csv/xml file.
If i go to Actions ->Export as csv/XML, i am not able to get the test steps. I get only the expected results section. Can someone help me out in this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not supported out of the box by Rally. You could write a script to do it using our [Web Service API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) or one of our [programming toolkits](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-apis).

- Mark

P.S. Rally uses StackOverflow for technical questions about coding to Rally Software's various APIs including the App SDK, Ruby & .NET APIs, and Web Service API not as much for questions about our product. You can always submit a [support case](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/help.sp?pp=contact) for product-related questions.